# Different results in graph and table

Tags: grafana

I have the below Grafana query, that is supposed to show max used memory Eden space per container for given time period. I found that when I show results in table they are different from results in graph. For example in table max used Eden space is 500M, while the graph for the same container reaches 1G.

How to solve it? Maybe for table Grafana reads only limited number of points?

> max by (container)
> (jvm_memory_used_bytes{cluster="$cluster",namespace="$namespace",
> id="Eden Space"})

Comment: I found that the numbers shown in table are the last numbers in data series. But I use max function! Why it happens that way? How to make it show the max?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what was wrong. The table was showing the last value and not the max for the whole time range. After changing it to below, it started to work fine:

> max by (container)
> (max_over_time(jvm_memory_used_bytes{cluster="$cluster",namespace="$namespace", id="Eden Space"}[$__range]))